# cannot be able to use "as" key word in DynamicTableEntity (Azure Table)

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure table where I have inserted heterogeneous entities. After the retrieval, I want to convert them to some specific type using "as". I tried to do this, but it threw the following error:

> Cannot be able to convert DynamicTableEntity to TestingEntity Via reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion,  wrapping conversion or null type conversion.

Is there any way I can convert my entities to a particular type?

My code is as follows:

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
                // Create the table client.
                CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

                CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TestingWithTableDatetime");
                // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
                table.CreateIfNotExists();
     TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> entityQuery =
                    new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>();
                var employees = table.ExecuteQuery(entityQuery);

                IEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity> entities = table.ExecuteQuery(entityQuery);
                foreach (var e in entities)
                {
                    EntityProperty entityTypeProperty;
                    if (e.Properties.TryGetValue("EntityType", out entityTypeProperty))
                    {
                        if (entityTypeProperty.StringValue == "SampleEntity1")
                        {
//Cannot be able to Use as
                            var TestingWithTableDatetime = e as SampleEntity1;
                        }
                        if (entityTypeProperty.StringValue == "SampleEntity2")
                        {
                            // Use entityTypeProperty, RowKey, PartitionKey, Etag, and Timestamp
                        }
                        if (entityTypeProperty.StringValue == "SampleEntity3")
                        {
                            // Use entityTypeProperty, RowKey, PartitionKey, Etag, and Timestamp
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Class definition for Sample1

```
 public class Sample1 : TableEntity
    {
        public Sample1(string pk, string rk)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = pk;
            this.RowKey = rk;
            EntityType = "MonitoringResources";
        }

        public string EntityType { get; set; }

        public Sample1()
        {
        }


    }
```

Things I have tried.I have created a class as Testing and in that I inherited Table entity.Then Testing is inherited by sample1 as follow

Testing Class definition

```
public class testing : TableEntity
    {
        public testing(string pk, string rk)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = pk;
            this.RowKey = rk; //MetricKey
        }

        public string EntityType { get; set; }

        public testing()
        {
        }
    }
```

modified Class sample1:

```
public class sample1 : testing
    {
        public sample1(string pk, string rk) : base(pk, rk)
        {
            EntityType = "sample1";
        }

        public sample1()
        {
        }
    }
```

In this i didnt get any error but 
when I am converting it to sample1 by using "as" it returns as null.

Finally I ended with creating some helper.

```
 public static class AzureManager
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Converts a dynamic table entity to .NET Object
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TOutput">Desired Object Type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="entity">Dynamic table Entity</param>
        /// <returns>Output Object</returns>
        public static TOutput ConvertTo<TOutput>(DynamicTableEntity entity)
        {
            return ConvertTo<TOutput>(entity.Properties, entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Convert a Dynamic Table Entity to A POCO .NET Object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TOutput">Desired Object Types</typeparam>
        /// <param name="properties">Dictionary of Table Entity</param>
        /// <returns>.NET object</returns>
        public static TOutput ConvertTo<TOutput>(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, string partitionKey, string rowKey)
        {
            var jobject = new JObject();
            properties.Add("PartitionKey", new EntityProperty(partitionKey));
            properties.Add("RowKey", new EntityProperty(rowKey));
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                WriteToJObject(jobject, property);
            }
            return jobject.ToObject<TOutput>();
        }

        public static void WriteToJObject(JObject jObject, KeyValuePair<string, EntityProperty> property)
        {
            switch (property.Value.PropertyType)
            {
                case EdmType.Binary:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.BinaryValue));
                    return;

                case EdmType.Boolean:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.BooleanValue));
                    return;

                case EdmType.DateTime:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.DateTime));
                    return;

                case EdmType.Double:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.DoubleValue));
                    return;

                case EdmType.Guid:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.GuidValue));
                    return;

                case EdmType.Int32:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.Int32Value));
                    return;

                case EdmType.Int64:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.Int64Value));
                    return;

                case EdmType.String:
                    jObject.Add(property.Key, new JValue(property.Value.StringValue));
                    return;

                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

the above one works for me.

```
var obj= AzureManager.ConvertTo<Sample1>(e);
```

If you find any other way.Please suggest.

Comment: Can you post the class definition of `SampleEntity1` for example?

Comment: Just a suggestion, rather than going ahead with `DynamicTableEntity`, try to override `WriteEntity()` and `ReadEntity()` methods. You will get similar results and query would be a lot easier. And as suggested by @PeterBons please edit your question and provide `SampleEntity1`.

Comment: If you want to stick to `DynamicTableEntity`, then go through the (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables). One of the section explains how to **Query a subset of entity properties**.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative and much simpler solution for you that is natively supported by Azure Storage SDK version > 8.0.0. You do not even need to write any transformation / conversion code :)

Have a look at:

TableEntity.Flatten method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt775434.aspx

TableEntity.ConvertBack method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt775432.aspx

These methods are provided by the SDK as static, standalone helper methods. Flatten method will convert your entities to a flat dictionary of entity properties where you can simply assign a partition key and row key, create a dynamictableentity from the flat dictionary and write to azure table storage.

When you want to read the entity back, read it as dynamic table entity and pass the property dictionary of the returned dynamic table entity to TableEntity.ConvertBack method. Just tell it which type of object you want the method to convert the property dictionary into, via its generic type parameter and it will do the conversion for you.

I originally implemented these api s as nuget packages and now they are integrated into azure storage sdk. If you want to read a bit more about how they work you can see the article I wrote originally about the nuget packages here:

https://doguarslan.wordpress.com/2016/02/03/writing-complex-objects-to-azure-table-storage/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can convert my entities to a particular type?

We could use [DynamicTableEntityConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicTableEntityConverter/) to do that.

According to your code, we could use the following code to  covert `DynamicTableEntity`  to `Sample1`

```
var TestingWithTableDatetime = DynamicTableEntityConverter.ConvertToPOCO<Sample1>(e);
```

Comment: I tried DynamicTableEntityConverter.ConvertToPOCO<Sample1>(e); but i am getting null value in Partition key as well as row key.